# postgress SQL state: 22P02

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy, delimiter

i have been trying to import this csv ino psql: COPY isse FROM'C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\nnn.csv'DELIMITER ',' HEADER CSV

and this error about "2,033" which has thousand comma popped up

also i need to work on numbers over thousand which definitely has comma.

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "2,033"
CONTEXT:  COPY isse, line 12, column monthly_sales: "2,033"
SQL state: 22P02

Answer (score 0):

First create the table structure accordingly.
Then use :

```
\COPY <table name> FROM 'location + file_name' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

where:

**\COPY**: This is the command to copy the record to / from the .csv file.

**<table_name>**: Provides the table name where you want to import the data.

**'location + file_name'**: An absolute path to the file (make sure you have read access to the file).

**DELIMITER ','**: Specifies the delimiter, which in our case is a comma: ‘,’.

**CSV** Specifies the file type from which we are going to import.

**HEADER** Signifies that we have a header row in our .csv file and while importing we should ignore the first row